# I used my Netflix account while on holiday abroad. How do I stop others at the same accommodation using it?

Tags: account-management, netflix

I live in the UK and have a Netflix account. While in France I was able to sign in to Netflix on my host's television box and watch movies - but forgot to sign out again.

How can I prevent others who use the same accommodation from using this Netflix account?

Comment: Start by changing your password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new [Netflix feature called "Managing Access and Devices"](https://about.netflix.com/en/news/giving-members-additional-control-over-their-account-managing-access-and-devices) which I accessed via the web version of Netflix. Use this screen to sign out devices in foreign countries.

[image]